# Implementing Skype like incoming call notification popup window using c++ win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to implement skype like incoming call notifier popup window using win32/c++. I searched a lot and couldn't achieve it. Basically my application have audio/video calling capability so if user is working with any other application, this incoming call notification is blinking to task bar. I found some work around to bring it to foreground but that is failing for around 20% calls.
Below are the links I had already referred to below pages.
1. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo

Comment: This is called a [*toast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Toast_(computing)).  Knowing the right search term should help you get unstuck.

Comment: Isn't it only for ios/android called toast ? ( In android the ui-class dfinitely has this name: "Toast").

Comment: Did you consider respecting the rules set by the OS and *NOT* steal the focus from the foreground app?

Comment: @icbytes No: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx

Comment: You are basically trying to subvert the system. Its really not nice to force a new focus window on the user, and Windows goes to lengths to stop you doing this and so its not surprising that you trying to hack through this you're failing some of the time. I dont know how skype does it, but are you sure its window has focus, and just isn't a toast like window which gets the user's attention?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan... I believe this link refer to Windows mobile development. What i am aware of about toast word in windows is available for windows8+ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MikeVine: I agree with you Mike. This is something which window haven't provided intentionally. Regarding your question-  I dont know how skype does it, but are you sure its window has focus, and just isn't a toast like window which gets the user's attention?

Comment: @dverma No, that link is not specific to WinMo

Comment: @MikeVine:
Regarding your question-  I dont know how skype does it, but are you sure its window has focus, and just isn't a toast like window which gets the user's attention?... If you are asking in regards to skype, No, Window doesn't have focus its only a toast like window which gets user's attention.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Yes this will work for me. I don't really want to steal the focus from foreground app. If a toast like window which gets the user's attention will do my job.

Comment: The skype notification is a top-level window but it doesn't take focus. So use `WS_EX_TOPMOST` when you create the window and use `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNA)` to display it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: No, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Sorry, had done a silly mistake. your trick works perfectly. Thanks.